# regex to match file path excluding ".."

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with Regex that allow dots but not double dots:

> **x/y/a.c** - match
>   **x/y/../a.c** - no match.

Thanks,

Comment: It depends on a regex flavor. BTW, why not use `if (s.Contains("..")) { /*FAIL*/}`?

Comment: Ok, a regex for you to check what tool/language you are using: `(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)`. If you need to just match a string with a `.` but that has no two dots, use `^(?!.*\.\.).*\..*$`. This won't work in RE2, or Bash.

Comment: Hi, there seem to be no support for lookahead in libc's regex()/regcomp(). When I include lookahead stuff, regcomp() fails with "regcomp failed: Invalid preceding regular expression". Any solution that doesn't involve lookhead? Thanks.

Comment: Of course regexcomp does not support lookarounds. That is why you must specify the language when posting regex answers. Use `^[^.]*[.][^.]*$`.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as `/(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)/` for doing [regex negative lookaheads/lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

To elaborate: This searches for a `.` (dot) which does not have another `.` (dot) around it. Where `(?<!\.)` is the negative lookbehind and consumes no characters, and the `(?!\.)` is the negative lookahead which also consumes no characters in the match.

Keep in mind that Javascript Regex cannot do lookbehinds.

Comment: awwww what, you just saw my answer and changed yours so it would have posted before mine https://postimg.org/image/78b4wfl5d/

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Sorry, I didn't see your answer in the time I was updating and re-reviewing it at all. It just happens to look that way.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to take your word for it ;-) no worries

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a negative lookahead and behind

```
(?<!.)\.(?!\.)
```

negative lookahead alone matches the second dot

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html